How to replace multiple substrings with different substitutions individually in one go WITHOUT REGEX?
I have seen a bunch of questions covering this exact topic here using something like this:
re.sub(r'(is)|(life)', lambda x: {'is': 'are', 'life': 'butterflies'}[x.group(0)], "There is no life in the void.")

But I haven't seen any attempts at solving the problem without regex. Anyway here is my attempt.
The problem is simple, given a string and a dictionary containing patterns and their corresponding replacements, replace every occurrence of the patterns in the string with their corresponding value in the dictionary, and leaving every character not part of the patterns unchanged; in case there are patterns with the same prefixes or one of the patterns is completely a prefix of another, the longest should always win.
All of these operations should be done in one loop.
Here is the code I came up with:
def multi_replace(text, groups):
    groups = dict(sorted(groups.items(), key=lambda x: -len(x[0])))
    i = 0
    pieces = []
    lengths = [len(pattern) for pattern in groups]
    l0 = lengths[0]
    L = len(text)
    while i < L:
        p = 0
        for pattern, replacement in groups.items():
            l = lengths[p]
            if text[i:i+l] == pattern:
                pieces.append(replacement)
                i += l
                break
            p += 1
        else:
            pieces.append(text[i:i+l0])
            i += l0
    
    return "".join(pieces)

It is as efficient as I can make it, I actually wrote it before I found the regex approach, and it is considerably less efficient than the regex approach:
In [61]: %timeit multi_replace("There is no life in the void.", {'is': 'are', 'life': 'butterflies'})
6.87 µs ± 31.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [62]: %timeit re.sub(r'(is)|(life)', lambda x: {'is': 'are', 'life': 'butterflies'}[x.group(0)], "There is no life in the void.")
3.09 µs ± 11.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

Is there anyway to make my function faster?

Is this question academic in nature? If there is regex, why not use it?

You could build a ternary search tree from the patterns and move through the tree for each letter of text. You have to keep multiple pointers into the tree but most of them should soon end nowhere and can be removed.

ok but are we talking without regex or without python's built in string.replace? whatever is happening in the while loop looks unnecessary

Exactly, so why not just return text.replace("is", "are").replace("life", "butterflies")? It doesn't use a regex.
